# How to share code between recipes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a recipe that loops through a bunch of data defined in the attributes:

```
node["repos"].each do |repo, data|
  ...do stuff...
end
```

the `...do stuff...` section is fairly long, and I would like to re-use it in multiple recipes, the only difference being that data set in the attributes is different.

I tried moving the inside of the loop to another recipe and including it like this:

```
node["repos"].each do |repo, data|
   include_recipe "other_recipe"
end
```

But when it tried to run `other_recipe`, the `data` variable did not exist.

What is the "proper" way of sharing code between recipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be is moving this `do stuff` to library.

*my_cookbook/libraries/myhelper.rb:*

```
module Myhelper
  def do_stuff( repo, data )
    [...you can use all kinds of resources here as in recipe...]
  end
end
```

Then you can use this module in recipes like that:

*another_cookbook/recipes/some_recipe.rb:*

```
extend Myhelper
do_stuff( node[:attribute1], node[:attribute2] )
```

Just make sure you add a dependency on `my_cookbook` in metadata:

*another_cookbook/metadata.rb:*

```
depends 'my_cookbook'
```

Comment: This kind of thing can be workable but is very much an advanced technique and I wouldn't recommend it to new users out of the gate :) lots of ways it can go wrong with minimal feedback since your mostly bypassing Chef itself and using it as a Ruby API

Comment: Creating a custom resource requires even more hassle.

Comment: Adding that line to the `metadata.rb` is only for if you want to use that library from another cookbook, correct?  If I want to use it in multiple recipes in the same cookbook, I assume that I wouldn't need that.

Comment: Yes, the line in metadata is required in the other cookbooks only.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't work because `include_recipe` both doesn't allow passing parameters and is "debounced" meaning it only runs once for a given recipe.

The simplest option these days for this kind of thing is to make a custom resource. Other options include definitions and helper methods but I would start with a custom resource and go from there. The inputs to the block of stuff (`repo` and `data` in this case) become resource properties and the chunk of recipe code goes in the resource's action method.